# Detect if sortable has been dragged out of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to detect when a sortable item has been dragged out of the container (or has been dropped outside of the container) so I can call a function if it has been selected and dropped inside the same container class.

### Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u3TH4/5/

```
$(".container").sortable({
    connectWith: ".button",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(!not-dragged-outside-of-container) {
            // a function here
        }
    }
});

$(".button").sortable({
    connectWith: ".container",
    tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the receive and remove callbacks. The item is in the ui object passed as the second argument: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-remove

Comment: Why do you have to do it in the stop event?

Comment: I need to check if the draggable (sortable) has been dropped inside or outside of the container. If it has not been dropped outside of the container I need to run a script..

Comment: You haven't explained why you have to use the stop event. Using the receive and remove events provide exactly the functionality you're after unless you already have code in the stop even that you need to interact with. Check out how I updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3TH4/6/